# Experiencing issues with saving documents and accessing user accounts after moving Home folder

Tags: hard-drive, user-account, folders

Recently I had a larger (2 TB) secondary SATA SSD installed in my iMac (running Big Sur)  in order to incorporate data from several external HDDs that are nearing the end of their effective lifespan. Since the Macintosh HD is a 256 GB drive I thought it practical to transfer the Home folder and other user folders to the secondary drive so it wouldn't be filled to capacity as soon as I started importing my external files. I followed this guide https://www.lifewire.com/move-macs-home-folder-new-location-2260157 and everything went smoothly at first.

However, after pointing the different user folders to the new locations in the secondary drive via the "Users and groups" interface I noticed that my wife could no longer sign in to her account. When I pointed her account back toward the original user folder on Macintosh HD this was no longer an issue. It's also proved impossible to save documents from Word to anything but the documents folders in the original users folders on the Macintosh HD.

Now I'm wondering what the issues are. Let me start by saying that I'm not really Mac-savvy to begin with and I suspect it's got something to do with ownership and levels of access to the different folders and drives, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to figure it out. Normally I wouldn't have attempted to root around with the Home folder and stuff, but the guide made it look so simple (silly me).

If anyone can give me some advice on how to solve this, or whether I should simply move the Home folder back to the Macintosh HD and try to keep pictures and other large folders on the secondary drive, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of macOS? The lifewire link article is using 10.13.

Comment: It's Big Sur (11), which I naturally didn't take into account...

Comment: I don't properly understand the BS changes, but something has changed with regards to Documents and Desktop which makes moving them away from the Macintosh HD problematic.  So short answer is to keep the home folder on the boot disk and create folders on the other disk for large folders and files.  Long answer is to wait for a better assistance.